# how to derive $\tilde{g}_{ij}$ from a given surface $x$

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, tensors, covariance

> Let $x(t, \phi) = (t\cos(\phi), t\sin(\phi),\log(\phi))$ describe a surface. 
> Calculate the metric tensor $g_{ij}$ and $\tilde{g}_{ij}$

Using the first fundamental form I get for $g_{ij}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1+\frac{1}{t^2} &0 \\ 
 0 & t^2
\end{pmatrix}$

However, I don't know how to express $\tilde{g}_{ij}$, if I am not mistaken it should be the covariant form of $g_{ij}$.
I'm confused on how to derive $\tilde{g}_{ij}$, any help is appreciated.

Edit:
I'm not sure how to interpret this definition of a covariant vector:

> A tensor having a transformation law that mimics that of the scalar field gradient 
> $$A^{'}_\mu (x^{'}) = \frac{ \partial x^{\nu} }{ \partial {x^{'}}^{\mu} }A_{\nu}(x) $$

Comment: What is the covariant form of $g_{ij}$? Can you include the definition

Comment: $\tilde{g}_{ij}$ is obtained when you give another parametrization of the same surface.